# hashmap.get(char c) returning null for only special chars only in linux

Tags: java, linux, null, hashmap

I don't understand this.  It only happens in linux (runs fine on my machine).  It only happens when there are special characters in the file that I'm reading.  Could this be a problem with linux and Character.equals()?

Code in another function calling `HashMap.get()`.  This prints "null" for each `Hashmap.get()` using a special char like Ã.

```
fis = new FileInputStream(fromFile);
int fromCharInt;
//read a byte at a time from the file
while ((fromCharInt = fis.read()) != -1) {
     System.out.println((char)fromCharInt);  //prints Ã
     System.out.println(hMap.get((char)fromCharInt));  //prints null
}
```

Generating the HashMap

```
private static HashMap<Character, String> generateMap(HuffmanTree hTree, List<FreqTracker> freqs)
{
    HashMap<Character, String> hMap = new HashMap<Character, String>();
    BinaryNode<FreqTracker> charNode;
    for (FreqTracker freq: freqs)
    {
        charNode = HuffmanTree.findCharNode(freq.getC(), hTree.getRoot());

        hMap.put(freq.getC(), HuffmanTree.getBinaryCode(charNode, ""));
    }

    return hMap;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's a character encoding issue.

Comment: The default charset on Linux is different from that on windows.

Comment: How should i debug this nonsense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a single byte from the InputStream (that's what InputStreams do...). Change it to a *Reader and open it with the correct character encoding, and read chars from the Reader, not bytes. Special characters are typically multiple bytes, and Linux is typically UTF-8 encoding by default, hence your problems

Comment: What encoding do you think that should be or how do I find out?  When I use System.out.println(fromCharInt) for Ã I get 195.  Isn't that only 1 byte?

Comment: not necessarily, it *could* be the double-byte \u00C3. Also, the Linux file may have byte-order marks in the file which would be interpreted correctly by a *Reader class. You can try with the default encoding for your system: FileReader fr = new FileReader("infile.name"); and use the fr.read() method.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you.  Wish I had made this post 10 hours earlier.

Comment: You are welcome. In general, in Java, if you work with text data, always use Readers and Writers. Input/Output Streams are for BINARY DATA ONLY.